# Optimizing vector creation

Tags: python, optimization, vector

I have a matrix with 1.000.000 rows, I read lines one by one, and would like to run a function on each element of a specific column. The elements in the relevant column are integers between 1 and 1115. The function is the following:

```
def vectorized_id(j):
    """Return a 1115-dimensional unit vector with a 1.0 in the j-1'th position
    and zeroes elsewhere.
    """
    j = j - 1    
    e = [0] * 1115
    e[j] = 1.0
    return e
```

The problem is that it is slow, and I would like to save time by optimizing it if it is possible. Can it be done faster?

Comment: you might try doing this in-line - remove the overhead of a function call, and get rid of j = j -1 - just do e[j-1] = 0

Comment: Consider using some kind of sparse data structure, e.g. - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/sparse.html